# How to count the number of letters in a string without the spaces?

Tags: python

This is my solution resulting in an error. Returns 0

PS: **I'd still love a fix to my code :)**

```
from collections import Counter
import string


def count_letters(word):
    global count
    wordsList = string.split(word)
    count = Counter()
    for words in wordsList:
        for letters in set(words):
            return count[letters]

word = "The grey old fox is an idiot"
print count_letters(word)
```

Comment: The error is that it returns 0

Comment: `len(word.replace(" ", ""))`

Comment: @AliGajani Are you sure that nested for loop does what you think it does? I'm almost positive that it doesn't do what you actually want.

Comment: The `count` variable is empty (it was not initialised with any collection). When you get `count[letters]`, it's guaranteed to be 0, like every other index in `count`. To count each letter in `word`, you need to use `Counter(word)`. But Matt's solution is better than that.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your use of "set()" here.  Your code, even fixing the above issue with Counter() not having something to count, will only give you the number of UNIQUE letters in the FIRST word.  The very first time through your inner loop, your function will exit, giving you a result of 3.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: After fiddling with it a bit, I edited my answer below to offer a version that uses the Counter class.

Comment: YOne of the errors in your code is that the `return` is nested in the inner loop, so you don't actually iterate over all items. You also don't need a global count.

Answer (score 23):

```
def count_letters(word):
    return len(word) - word.count(' ')
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple letters to ignore, you could filter the string:

```
def count_letters(word):
    BAD_LETTERS = " "
    return len([letter for letter in word if letter not in BAD_LETTERS])
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. can you please show me the explanation of word.count in Python Docs, a link perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Matt, it doesn't talk about the usage of this ' '. Can you enlighten us more about how does it work, what other things can we do with it.

Comment: @AliGajani, the explanation in the link Matt gave says that it counts the number of non-overlapping occurrences of the given string parameter. If the given string is a space (`' '`), then it counts the number of spaces. So `len(word) - word.count(' ')` returns the length of the whole string minus the number of spaces that are in `word`, which gives the desired result.

Comment: Right, I get that, but Python docs talk about str.count(s,sub[start-end]). How does the str.count(' ') fit into the scheme of things here considering the Python syntax.

Comment: @AliGajani The Python syntax stated in the link is `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])` so the solution above uses the `str.count(sub)` case of that syntax, which doesn't specify the start or end. Optionally, just the start could be specified, or both start and end.

Comment: Awesome, anyone willing to fix my existing code. Thanks for all those awesome solutions by the way. I'd still love to find a fix for my existing code and how I can gracefully count the letters once I get those strings split into a WordList.

Answer (score 13):

Simply solution using the [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
sum(c != ' ' for c in word)
```

It's a memory efficient solution because it uses a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) rather than creating a temporary list and then calculating the sum of it.

It's worth to mention that `c != ' '` returns `True or False`, which is a value of type `bool`, but `bool` is a subtype of `int`, so you can sum up bool values (`True` corresponds to `1` and `False` corresponds to `0`)

You can check for an inheretance using the `mro` method:

```
>>> bool.mro() # Method Resolution Order
[<type 'bool'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'object'>]
```

Here you see that `bool` is a subtype of `int` which is a subtype of `object`.

Comment: Here it worth pointing out that, when used in numeric contexts, `True` and `False` behave like the integers `1` and `0`. It couldn't be obvious.

Answer (score 6):

MattBryant's answer is a good one, but if you want to exclude more types of letters than just spaces, it will get clunky. Here's a variation on your current code using `Counter` that will work:

```
from collections import Counter
import string

def count_letters(word, valid_letters=string.ascii_letters):
    count = Counter(word) # this counts all the letters, including invalid ones
    return sum(count[letter] for letter in valid_letters) # add up valid letters
```

Example output:

```
>>> count_letters("The grey old fox is an idiot.") # the period will be ignored
22
```

Comment: If you replace BAD_LETTERS = " " with BAD_LETTERS = [" ", "."], his code will work just as yours.

Comment: @AnonymousPi: The accepted answer was edited three minutes after mine went up. At the time I wrote this answer, only the `len(word) - word.count(" ")` part was there, which was what I thought would be awkward to extend. The naive extension to excluding multiple kinds of characters, `len(word) - sum(word.count(letter) for letter in BAD_LETTERS)` would be very slow (which is why MattBryant didn't suggest it!).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to condense it into two lines of code:

```
string = input("Enter your string\n")
print(len(string) - string.count(" "))
```

Answer (score 4):

Counting number of letters in a string using regex.

```
import re
s = 'The grey old fox is an idiot'
count = len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]',s))
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, if that's what you want, here's what I would do to fix your existing code:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_letters(words):
    counter = Counter()
    for word in words.split():
        counter.update(word)
    return sum(counter.itervalues())

words = "The grey old fox is an idiot"
print count_letters(words)  # 22
```

If you don't want to count certain non-whitespace characters, then you'll need to remove them -- inside the `for` loop if not sooner.

Answer (score 3):

For another one-liner solution:

```
def count_letters(word):  return len(filter(lambda x: x not in " ", word))
```

This works by using the filter function, which lets you pick the elements of a list  that return true when passed to a boolean-valued function that you pass as the first argument.  I'm using a lambda function to make a quick, throwaway function for that purpose.

```
>>> count_letters("This is a test")
11
```

You could easily extend this to exclude any selection of characters you like:

```
def count_letters(word, exclude):  return len(filter(lambda x: x not in exclude, word))

>>> count_letters ("This is a test", "aeiou ")
7
```

Edit:  However, you wanted to get your own code to work, so here are some thoughts.  The first problem is that you weren't setting a list for the Counter object to count.  However, since you're looking for the total number of letters, you need to join the words back together again rather than counting each word individually.  Looping to add up the number of each letter isn't really necessary because you can pull out the list of values and use "sum" to add them.

Here's a version that's as close to your code as I could make it, without the loop:

```
from collections import Counter
import string

def count_letters(word):
   wordsList = string.split(word)
   count = Counter("".join(wordsList))
   return sum(dict(count).values())

word = "The grey old fox is an idiot"
print count_letters(word)
```

Edit:  In response to a comment asking why not to use a for loop, it's because it's not necessary, and in many cases using the many implicit ways to perform repetitive tasks in Python can be faster, simpler to read, and more memory-efficient.

For example, I could have written

```
joined_words = []
for curr_word in wordsList:
    joined_words.extend(curr_word)
count = Counter(joined_words)
```

but in doing this I wind up allocating an extra array and executing a loop through the Python interpreter that my solution:

```
count = Counter("".join(wordsList))
```

would execute in a chunk of optimized, compiled C code.  My solution isn't the only way to simplify that loop, but it's one way.

Comment: Nice to see you not using the loop, but why?

Comment: The main reason not to use the loop is that it's not necessary.  Python provides many ways to perform repetitive tasks implicitly, and these techniques are often faster.  I'll edit my answer to explain a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

```
n=str(input("Enter word: ").replace(" ",""))

ans=0
for i in n:
    ans=ans+1
print(ans)
```

Comment: I think `len(n)` would work fine, instead of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found this is working perfectly

```
str = "count a character occurance"
str = str.replace(' ', '')
print (str)
print (len(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_letter(string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i].isalpha():
            count += 1
    return count


print(count_letter('The grey old fox is an idiot.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word_display = ""
for letter in word:
    if letter in known:
        word_display = "%s%s " % (word_display, letter)
    else:
        word_display = "%s_ " % word_display
return word_display
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please describe how this works and/or what is different from the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

```
string=str(input("Enter any sentence: "))
s=string.split()
a=0
b=0

for i in s:
    a=len(i)
    b=a+b

print(b)
```

It works perfectly without counting spaces of a string

Answer (score -3):

Try using...

```
resp = input("Hello, I am stuck in doors! What is the weather outside?")
print("You answered in", resp.ascii_letters, "letters!")
```

Didn't work for me but should work for some random guys.

Comment: This does not work. `resp` object will have no `ascii_letters` attribute. And more importantly, does not answer the question being asked