# How do I make it where the code ignores every symbol within a string except for those in a list?

Tags: python, encryption

I was trying to make a program that could be used for one-time pad encryption by counting the number of characters and having a random number for each one. I started making a line that would let the program ignore spaces, but then I realized I would also need to ignore other symbols. I had looked at  *[How to count the number of letters in a string without the spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455222/how-to-count-the-number-of-letters-in-a-string-without-the-spaces)* for the spaces, 
and it proved very helpful. However, the answers only show how to remove one symbol at a time. To do what I would like by using that answer, I would have to have a long line of  `- how_long.count('`*character*`')`'s, and symbols that I may not even know of may still be copied in. Thus, I am asking for a way where it will only count all the alphabetic characters I write down in a list. Is this possible, and if so, how would it be done?

My code:

```
import random
import sys

num = 0

how_long = input("Message (The punctuation will not be counted)\n     Message: ")
charNum = len(how_long) - how_long.count(' ')

print("\n")
print("Shift the letters individually by their respective numbers.")

for num in range(0, charNum-1):
    sys.stdout.write(str(random.randint(1, 25))+", ")
print(random.randint(1, 25))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to find the number of letters in the input:

```
import re, sys, random
how_long = input("Message (The punctuation will not be counted)\n     Message: ")

regex_for_letters = "[A-Za-z]"

letter_count = 0
for char in how_long: 
    check_letter = re.match(regex_for_letters, char)
    if check_letter:
        letter_count += 1
print(letter_count)

for num in range(0, letter_count-1):
    sys.stdout.write(str(random.randint(1, 25))+", ")
print(random.randint(1, 25))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your desired outcome is to clean a string so it only contains a desired subset of characters the following will work but, I'm not sure I totally understand what your question is so you will probably have to modify somewhat.

```
desired_letters = 'ABCDOSTRY'
test_input = 'an apple a day keeps the doctor away'
cleaned = ''.join(l for l in test_input if l.upper() in desired_letters)
# cleaned == 'aaadaystdoctoraay'
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the string:

```
source_string='My String'
allow_chars=['a','e','i','o','u'] #whatever characters you want to accept
source_string_list=list(source_string)

source_string_filtered=list(filter(lambda x: x in allow_chars,source_string_list))
```

the count would be: `len(source_string_filtered)`