# How to count the number of letters in a multiple list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, character

So I am having problems in my python code. I need to count the number of letters in a list. I am not really sure what to use as I have to use for loop to do it. example is shown below

```
names = ['Taylor Hudson','Mary Jane','Tom Curise']
```

to print the number of letters in each name eg 12, 8, 8

Comment: Are you having trouble with the for loop or getting the letter count for strings? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455222/how-to-count-the-number-of-letters-in-a-string-without-the-spaces) talks about how to count letters.

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```
>>> names= ['Taylor Hudson','Mary Jane','Tom Curise']
>>> print [len(i.replace(' ','')) for i in names]
[12, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried counting the time taken by 5 different methods using `timeit`.

```
import timeit
import re

names = ['Taylor Hudson','Mary Jane','Tom Curise']

def method1():         #By lenik
    [len(i.replace(' ','')) for i in names]

def method2():         #Using Regez
    [len(re.findall("[^ ]", _)) for _ in names]

def method3():         #Using sum
    [sum(1 for c in i if c!=' ')  for i in names]

def method4():         #Using split
    [len("".join(i.split())) for i in names]

def method5():         #using len and count
    [len(i)-i.count(" ") for i in names]

print(timeit.timeit(method1))
print(timeit.timeit(method2))
print(timeit.timeit(method3))
print(timeit.timeit(method4))
print(timeit.timeit(method5))
```

Output:

> 1.4044888
>   9.915313600000001
>   4.8790482
>   1.7563844999999993
>   1.3532711000000006

So the fastest method is method 5:

```
>>> names= ['Taylor Hudson','Mary Jane','Tom Curise']
>>> [len(i)-i.count(" ") for i in names]
[12, 8, 9]
>>>
```